# Is there a way to correlate or find out the host of a virtual machine?

Tags: security, virtualization, tor

I'm learning about security and wondering, if I'm using a VM on any host (Windows or GNU/Linux) is it possible for someone (either in the same network or not) to gather information about my host (ip, mac address, location, etc.)

Is it possible using only a certain hypervisor (hyper-v, virtualvox,vmware,etc) or certain host?

I read that using Tails in a Virtual Machine is not that secure, because the host can compromise a guest and vice versa. How come?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it is possible clearly depends on virtual machine monitor (VMM) and host OS settings, and security mechanisms available/used.

Ideally, on a host system that strictly adheres to [Goldberg-Popek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popek_and_Goldberg_virtualization_requirements) conditions for virtualization, it is possible to write a hypervisor that provides full isolation. However, this fully applies to a simple hypothetical machine used in that paper. It says nothing about multicore systems, networking, or timing issues.

In reality, both software defects and hardware bugs/errata/oddities as last but not least poor configuration lead to situations where at least some information about host can be collected from within a guest.

If both host and guest are placed in the same network segment, one can easily learn some properties of the host by, for example, using `nmap` [network scanner](https://nmap.org/) and comparing against known OS signatures.

If there is no network access but some other resources are shared (files on a shared virtual folder), their careful study can reveal a lot. Like, if you see `c:\program files` shared with a Linux system, it gives a hint about host's OS.

Certain properties of many hypervisors can be seen simply by inspecting system resources. Examples: CPUID instruction can report "KVMKVMKVM" on KVM; disk vendor string can tell you that it is "Virtutech drive" for Wind River Simics; presence of Xen's paravirtual devices is an obvious thing to guess that maybe the host is Xen; etc. Typically, commercial hypervisors do not have a goal to mimic real hardware as closely as possible.

If a VMM is set up to hide such apparent blunders, there  still are numerous differences in behavior between real hardware and virtualized one. One of the most famous is [Red Pill](https://web.archive.org/web/20070911024318/http://invisiblethings.org/papers/redpill.html), but similar detection techniques are many, and at least some of them are documented in academical papers available on the Net.

It is hard to account for all of difference in machine instructions behavior, because of the complexity of underlying host architecture. For example, the architecture manual for very popular Intel 64 and IA-32 systems has more than 4000 [pages](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf) describing its official behavior. Not all corner cases are apparent/easy to implement/documented/well-defined/well-studied/not affected by errata. And AMD's processors that implement "the same" x86 architecture have their own manual for AMD64; and not always all things are pretty and unambiguously defined in these two books. The same applies to IBM's ARM's MIPS's processors.

Going deeper, there are timing/side channel details of computer operation which are even harder to account for when writing a hypervisor. The signal/noise ratio for analysis of timings is lower (i.e., it is easier to make a mistake and detect a real hardware as VMM, or vice versa), but it is still valid. The security community only recently started widely exploring attacks based on timings (see the Spectre/Meltdown family), and VMMs are not excluded from begin potential targets of such attacks.

> I read that using Tails in a Virtual Machine is not that secure, because the host can compromise a guest and vice versa. How come?

Unless something is formally proven, it cannot be relied upon 100%. Software can rarely be proven to be formally correct. In governmental/military applications, a sense  of "security" can be assured by passing certain very strict certifications. Only few specialized operating systems are certified to be free of bugs. Tails is not one of them. Besides all the reasons above, there can simply be a bug or misconfiguration in it that allows data to leak to those who look for it.